# Making the source code of my website open source: dos and don'ts?

Tags: open-source

I would like to get some advice from experienced webmasters about a specific issue: making the source code of a website open source.

To be perfectly clear, I am an amateur who started some years ago to work on a small website built from scratch (i.e., no framework besides jQuery and very few libraries) and developed from time to time, mostly as a kind of personal exercise to update and maintain my knowledge on the typical Web languages (i.e., HTML5, CSS3, PHP, SQL and JavaScript with jQuery).

Since I don't intend to make my website a commercial/professional one, I decided to eventually release its source code on my GitHub, as I believe the whole experience could be benefitial to other people learning web development (despite that it's not truly a *state-of-the-art* approach).

However, I have little to no clue on how often websites are made open source and how it's usually done. In particular, I have the following questions:

- **How much should I document my code ?** The source code in itself already has conventions to describe each file (such as file headers, DOxygen-like doc for functions/methods, etc.; since there's a large time span between each new additions to the code, it already helps me to know what I previously did). However, I was wondering whether I should add additional documents in my repository describing the general design or not (e.g., a PDF file). Consider that I don't use any common framework (besides jQuery) and that I made, for instance, a custom template system.
- **What should I be wary of regarding the security of my website ?** I.e., as the code will be publicly available, I am wondering if I should be extra cautious with some of its parts (like forms, interactions with AJAX, etc.). Consider that I will already remove passwords and that I secured forms (+ anything obtained with $_GET in PHP) and dialog with the database (as best as I could).
- **Where can I go to advertise and discuss the project with other webmasters ?** I know there's a Code Review website on StackExchange, but its rules (stating a question *must* provide a piece of code) let me think that it's not suited for my case. Besides, I would be more interested in a review of the overall architecture than a detailed review of each script.

Of course, you are free to mention and discuss other potential issues I didn't anticipate. Thanks a lot in advance for your kind answers.

**P.S.:** the website is currently online [here](https://www.projectag.org/) and mostly provides reviews for various video games. It's entirely in French.

Comment: I'm going to flag this as off-topic because any answer would be opinion-based. However, IMHO, if you are going to make the code 'open source'... do it in a book. At least then you can do it in an instructional format (which would be more beneficial) than just "here's the code".

Comment: I'll take it as a positive answer to my first question (i.e., in short, should I take the time to make a comprehensive document with LaTeX or not). Sorry if the topic is a bit too broad.

Comment: Don't pick the wrong license for your open source code. I picked MIT License to share my open source code with the public repository users so that we could grow branches. If you picked the wrong open source code license sharing open source code would cripple or limit the other users of that shared open source code that should have been able to branch off.